# How to share multiple dictionaries between processes

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I use the multiprocessing package for a multi-layered application and I want to share multiple dicts within a few processes.

I found the multiprocessing.Manager class already but it seems like it provides only one dict (Manager.dict()) per application. For me it looks like something like a [singleton object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What makes you think that they are singleton objects?  I don't see anything in the documentation that leads me to believe that you can't have more than one (although, the more managers you have, the less you'll reap the speed up benefits of multiprocessing)

Comment: I instantiated it multiple times, then I added key-value-pairs. Every key-value-pair appeared in all "instances".
Additionally I couldn't find any example/best practice/pythonic way to share multiple dictionaries. All examples look like [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).

Comment: Do you want to *modify* the dicts? Because if you don't need to do that, you can just create the dicts *before* creating `Process` instances and than every `Process` will "inherit" them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, a single `Manager` instance can manage multiple independent `dict`.  Here's a simple example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def f(x, d1, d2):
    if x == 1:
        d1['foo'] = 'bar'
    if x == 2:
        d2['bar'] = 'foo'
    print x, d1, d2
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = Manager()
    d1 = manager.dict()
    d2 = manager.dict()
    p1 = Process(target=f, args=(1, d1, d2))
    p2 = Process(target=f, args=(2, d1, d2))
    p3 = Process(target=f, args=(3, d1, d2))
    processes = [p1, p2, p3]
    for p in processes:
        p.start()
    for p in processes:
        p.join()
```

I get the following output:

```
3 {'foo': 'bar'} {}
1 {'foo': 'bar'} {}
2 {'foo': 'bar'} {'bar': 'foo'}
```

There is variation depending on which process gets to the dict's lock the fastest:

```
mgilson:$ python ~/sandbox/test.py
3 {'foo': 'bar'} {}
1 {'foo': 'bar'} {}
2 {'foo': 'bar'} {'bar': 'foo'}
mgilson:$ python ~/sandbox/test.py
1 {'foo': 'bar'} {'bar': 'foo'}
2 {'foo': 'bar'} {'bar': 'foo'}
3 {'foo': 'bar'} {'bar': 'foo'}
mgilson:$ python ~/sandbox/test.py
1 {'foo': 'bar'} {'bar': 'foo'}
3 {'foo': 'bar'} {'bar': 'foo'}
2 {'foo': 'bar'} {'bar': 'foo'}
mgilson:$ python ~/sandbox/test.py
1 {'foo': 'bar'} {}
2 {'foo': 'bar'} {'bar': 'foo'}
3 {'foo': 'bar'} {'bar': 'foo'}
```

but it is obvious that in each case, the dictionaries are distinct (they have different keys).

FWIW, I'm using OS-X.  There are some subtleties in how `multiprocessing` works on windows vs other *Nix systems that may come into play here...